# How was manu born according to Vedas?

Tags: vedas, manu, brahmanas

In bhagvata purana and vishnu purana it mentions that he was born from body of brahma, along with satarupa, what do Vedas say?

Comment: Do you want answers only from Veda?

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani yup.

Comment: OK. I doubted because you have accepted the answer that is quoting from Vishnu Purana.

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani I didn't check the link.

Answer (score 2):

Vedas also say the same thing that he was born out of Brahma, [refer](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp041.htm):

> 51:5 Brahmá, after detaching from himself the property of anger, in
>   the form of Rudra, converted himself into two persons, the first male,
>   or the Manu Swáyambhuva, and the first woman, or Śatarúpá: so in the
>   Vedas; 'So himself was indeed (his) son.'

Comment: Is vishnu Puran vedas?he asked from Vedic scriptures.